# How to sort Arraylist<Hashmap<String,String>>

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

Here I am having one query in which I am getting name and value as per the condition,I am storing value of empid and empname in List

Here is some piece of code:

```
List<String> _empid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> _empname = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here in which I am getting values from database:

```
while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
if (cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("name"))
        .equalsIgnoreCase("DIS_FIELD_COLLECTION_EXECUTIVE")) {

         _empid.add(cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("value")));

   } else if (cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("name"))
                  .equalsIgnoreCase("FIELD_EXECUTIVE_NAME")) {

         _empname.add(cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("value")));

   }
}

 for (int i = 0; i < _empid.size(); i++) {
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          map.put("id", _empid.get(i));
          map.put("name", _empname.get(i));

          Log.e("forloop", _empid.get(i));
          Log.e("forloop", _empname.get(i));

          emp.add(map);
          adp_emp = new Listadapter_emp(emp, Tracker_filter_Activity.this);
                        lst_employee.setAdapter(adp_emp);
}
```

Here The output is coming like this

```
01-17 12:16:49.696 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 5
01-17 12:16:49.696 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: AZAD NAGAR-TAN001    
01-17 12:16:49.697 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 3
01-17 12:16:49.697 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: PURVANG PANDYA-FPP022
01-17 12:16:49.698 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 2
01-17 12:16:49.698 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: TWESTT TESST-TTT001    
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 9
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: SDSDHH XDGHGSDFHGSD-TSX001    
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 8
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: TEST TEST-TTT002    
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: 6
01-17 12:16:49.699 29369-29369/com.wp.focus E/forloop: AZADALAM NAGAR-TAN002
```

Required output is name should be sorted as per alphabetical order and id should be arrange as per name i.e
Required Output like:

```
AZAD NAGAR-TAN001            5
AZADALAM NAGAR-TAN002        6
PURVANG PANDYA-FPP022        3
SDSDHH XDGHGSDFHGSD-TSX001   9
TEST TEST-TTT002             8
TWESTT TESST-TTT001          2
```

Thus ID should adjust as per sorted name,I am getting name and ID but not in sorted manner I had used various examples from google still not find.Will be grateful if this is solved thank you.

Comment: Java is an Object-Oriented language. You should use it. Create an `Employee` class with fields `id` and `name`. Then create an `ArrayList<Employee>` and sort it using `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName))` (Java 8). Or for Java 7, create an `EmployeeNameComparator` and sort using `Collections.sort(new EmployeeNameComparator())`.

Comment: Ok sir may be this will help me....let me try..thank you.

Comment: How to i set the Employee as i have to take id and name from different columns??

Comment: Your answer help me thanks alot.... @andreas

Answer (score 6):

You can use **tree map** which stores data in sorted manner.
Secondly, you can put **name against Id(key)** in map.

And if you still wants to use in in the same way then you can use `Collections.sort()` to sort your list.

Comment: There are loads of examples out there. Use your favourite search engine. @Abhi